# Mockito : How to ignore transitive dependencies

Tags: java, junit, mockito, classnotfoundexception

I am using mockito for my unit tests. Consider the following snippet

```
ThirdPartyClass tpo = mock(ThirdPartyClass.class);
doNothing().when(tpo).someMethod();
```

`ThirdPartyClass` is from a third party jar, lets say `tp.jar`. Now `tp.jar` is not an uber jar. Here is what `ThirdPartyClass` looks like

```
class ThirdPartyClass
{
    SomeOtherClass memberObject;

    public ThirdPartyClass(){}

    /*Rest of the code*/
}
```

Now, when i try to run my unit tests, i get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for `SomeOtherClass`. Remember that `tp.jar` is not an uber jar so it makes sense that `SomeOtherClass` is not in my classpath.

But why is mockito not able to handle this transitive dependency? Is there any way to ignore all transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 7):

[*"Only mock types that you own"*](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own) is the way to go here.
One reason for that is exactly what you describe: the test set up becomes too complicated, e.g. because of dependencies.

So instead of mocking the `ThirdPartyClass`, you create some sort of Adapter and then mock that class.

```
interface ThirdPartyAdapter {
   void someMethod(); // only put method here that you really use
}
```

And then mock that thing instead:

```
ThirdPartyAdapter tpo = mock(ThirdPartyAdapter.class);
doNothing().when(tpo).someMethod();
```

And in production, delegate to the `ThirdPartyClass`:

```
class UsefulThing implements ThirdPartyAdapter {
   ThirdPartyClass wrapped;

   UsefulThing(ThirdPartyClass wrapped) {
     this.wrapped = wrapped;
   }

   @Override
   void someMethod() {
     wrapped.someMethod()
   }
}
```

Benefits:

- Tests and production code is more robust to changes of the third party classes
- You can use your own domain terms for methods instead of what the third party dictates
- The relationship between your code and the third party code becomes clearer (and is only visible at a single place in your code)

I highly recommend [Growing Object Oriented Software by Freeman & Pryce](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) - or check the [mockito docks](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests) for a quick start.

Answer (score 4):

Mockito works by creating a subclass of the class to be mocked. So the class to be mocked has to compile. Could perhaps be solved by adding the jar that contains `SomeOtherClass` to your dependency management with scope `test`.

Comment: makes sense, but for that i will have to update my pom. and besides, i might not know about all of the class referenced in `ThirdPartyClass`

Comment: Usually maven should handle the resolving of transitive dependencies out of the box. Show your maven dependency for the class to be mocked.

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>asd.pqw.fgh</groupId>
   <artifactId>tp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: thats all i do to get tp.jar using maven

Comment: You would need to inspect the pom file of your dependency then, it might be that it uses a certain scope for its dependencies, making them non-transitive. If so, you can copy the dependency in question, and make it scope test.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to mock `ThirdPartyClass` then `SomeOtherClass` MUST be on your compile-time and runtime classpath. Without seeing how you are building/running it's difficult to give real help

You need to ensure that all the required classes (jars) are on

1. The compile classpath
2. The runtime classpath

If you are using a build tool like [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) to build & run then the classpaths, including transitive dependencies, will be managed for you. If you are compiling/running by hand you will need to ensure that the transitive dependencies are on the compile-time & runtime classpaths.