# Why does Mockito require private fields of mocked classes to be on the test runtime?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

When mocking a concrete class, it appears that Mockito accesses the private member fields of the mocked class. On the project I'm working upon we're actively limiting the transitivity of modules, and so if the type of the private member field is in another module which isn't visible at runtime, we get NoClassDefFoundError.

For example:

```
/**
 * In module M2
 */
public class C2 {
}    

/**
 * In module M1, module M2 is within compile scope.
 */
public class C1 {
  private C2;

  public String hello() {
    return "hi";
  }
}


/**
 * Module M1 is in compile scope, M2 not visible.
 */
@Test
public void test() {
  C1 instance = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(C1.class);
}
```

Running the above will result in:

```
Underlying exception : java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type C2 not present
```

Of course, if the interface I1 for C1 is extracted and mocked by the test, then all is well because I1 has no reference to C2.

Clearly there are ways around this (extracting an interface, add explicit link to module M2), but each of these approaches will require quite a lot of work. Questions are:

1. Why does Mockito to see things it shouldn't care about?
2. Is it possible / viable to stop Mockito requiring the type of
   private member fields to be available at runtime?

Comment: I think this is fundamentally the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49154772/1426891) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154894/1426891): in order to mock, Mockito is effectively compiling a subclass of C1 at test runtime, which (due to visibility) is inherently trickier than creating a class that implements an interface. If you agree, I'll close this question as a duplicate of that Q&A.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Thanks for finding that.